# Redis distributed locking for radix

Tags: go, redis, synchronization, mutex

I am using https://github.com/mediocregopher/radix as my redis client. Previously with go-redis I used redislock for distributed locking. Are there any such package for radix too?

Comment: How about https://github.com/creker/redislock-radix

Comment: It's not a very active repository

Answer (score 1):

you can doit using `SETNX` actually that is the way that redislock does it underneath, you can see how  do it [here](https://redis.io/commands/setnx/#design-pattern-locking-with-setnx). I hope this works for you